# Adding a column to a Navbar Dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to add a column to academic affairs so I can have two groups of four links adjacent to each other but I have failed at every attempt. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
</button><div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <button
       <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">IBHE</a>
        </div><!--enf of navbar-header -->

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Executive Director's Corner</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Meet Dr. James Applegate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>
     <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">        Academic Affairs</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">IBHE Approval & Review</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Academic Degree Programs</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Colleges & Universities </a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SARA</a></li> 

    <li class="divider"></li>

     <li><a href="#">Enrollment & Degrees</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Transfer of Academic Credits</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">P-20 Education Pipeline</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Underrepresented Groups</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Distance Education</a></li>
```

Comment: Any exmaple, i mean a visual example of what you need?

Comment: Also try to post the complete html but just of the piece of the nav bar

Comment: Try to post complete code but from the the looks of it you have unordered lists and if you want to add a column you should consider using a <table> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Thanks for replying and I will  definitely look into that link, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using bootstrap, here is what i recomend below will give you an example of a few different Column layouts in dropdown part of the menu.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
  min-width: 400px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-3 {
  min-width: 600px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333;
  white-space: normal;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #999;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
    min-width: 240px !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <!--/.navbar-header-->

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">One Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Two Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here that's extra long so we can see how it looks</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Three Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
</nav>
<!--/.navbar-->
```

External resources being used:

Important:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thanks Rich I will try this as soon as i get home from work.